# is there an HTML5 responsive generator on ubuntu?

Tags: tools, html5

I develop a web application and I do not have time for the frontend part, so I need a tool under Ubuntu that offers me to generate a html code, for example drag and drop divs or tables or input, a another point that is important the html code must be responsive.
someone has a solution to propose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several HTML5 generator I've used generators online but I think [UIkindle HTML UI Builder windows tool](https://madstreet.herokuapp.com/#) will help you to build your web application, to execute this software under ubuntu you have two possibilities with either via wine or install them in the virtual machine. 
 to get an idea about this tool see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPmAi2g2EWA)

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestions